# How can versioning in the package.json file of npm packages be understood?

Tags: node.js, npm, semantic-versioning

I want to know how the versioning works in `package.json` in a development cycle.

What is the meaning of each number in one `package.json` version property, such as the one below?

```
{
    "name": "A NodeJS Project",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    ...
}
```

Comment: Read about [semantic versioning](http://semver.org/spec/v1.0.0.html?utm_source=buffer&utm_campaign=Buffer&utm_content=buffer6cd8b&utm_medium=twitter)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not semver. It's semver-looking version number. Package version is not required to follow semantics of semver, it's just sorted like semver.

Usually these three digits have this meaning:

- First number called `major` is incremented when there are big changes that will very likely require substantial changes to your application on an update.
- Second number called `minor` is incremented when there are small changes that mostly backward compatible. It might break some applications, but it's an exception.
- Third number called `micro` is incremented almost every time a new version is pushed to npm. It is considered a bad practice to include breaking changes in micro updates, but even npm itself do it sometimes.

But it is not set in stone, and basically you can pick every version number you want. For example, `esprima-fb` package uses versioning like this: `1001.1001.2000-dev-harmony-fb`. These numbers have meaning too, but it's obviously not semver.

---

**edit**: I would like to include balupton's definition of version numbers from [twitter](https://twitter.com/balupton/status/430248212117454849), since it does reflect current status quo more precisely.

> - revisions = no b/c breaks
> - minors = b/c breaks for some
> - majors = b/c breaks for everyone

... where b/c means backward compatibility

Comment: What the meaning between semver itself to semver-looking version number, since the semantics of semver is parse versions with the pattern x.y.z? 

sorry for the english!

Comment: Semver attaches meaning to those three digits. There is no such requirement in npm and never will be. That's the difference.

npm uses two things from semver spec - format and sorting.

Comment: semver calls the third component **patch**, not **micro**, reflecting its intent: to provide patches (bug fixes). Saying that npm's relation to semver is purely _formal_ in nature doesn't tell the full story, which, methinks, is: while there is a reasonable _expectation_ that npm packages comply with semver, there is no _guarantee_, and there are definitely exceptions.

Comment: "patch" is a **fourth** component in 4-component version numbering systems. So it creates ambiguity when you're using it in 3-component system. See [github discussion](https://github.com/mojombo/semver/issues/160) for details.

Answer (score 7):

The `package.json` files used by npm follow the semantic versioning model. It follows the `major.minor.patch` pattern. There is a whole site dedicated to explaining the semantic versioing process at http://semver.org/. You should also have a look at the npm version man page, which gives a few more details: https://npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-version.html.

Comment: For sure, I considerer best explanation the paragraphs 6 7 8 from [semver](http://semver.org).

Comment: +1; this answer is superior to the accepted one; to find the middle ground: while there is a reasonable _expectation_ that npm packages comply with semver (semantic versioning), there is no _guarantee_ that they do, and there are definitely exceptions.